# Yii2: Update user permissions

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to update user including his permissions. This is how i'm doing it. Seems i'm missing something but i don't know what it is yet.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
$model = $this->findModel($id);
$perfis = $model->authAssignment;

foreach ($perfis as $perfil) {
  array_push($model->perfil_array, $perfil->item_name);
}

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
  $itemsSaved = false;
  $permissionsList = Yii::$app->request->post()['User']['perfil_array'];
  if (!empty($permissionsList)) {
      foreach ($permissionsList as $permission) {
         $newPermission = new AuthAssignment;
         $newPermission->item_name = $permission;
         $newPermission->user_id = $id;
         if($newPermission->save()){
            print_r("ok");
         } else {
            print_r($newPermission->getErrors()); die;
         }
      }
   }
   if ($model->save()) {
      $itemsSaved = true;
   } else {
     print_r($model->getErrors());die;
     return $this->render('update', [
     'model' => $model,]);
   }
   if ($itemsSaved) {
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
   }
}
return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model,]);
}
```

I'm getting all the posted permissions from the form checkboxes and save it to AuthAssignment table but it throwing this error.

```
Array
(
    [item_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => The combination "Admin"-"10" of Item Name and User ID has already been taken.
        )

    [user_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => The combination "Admin"-"10" of Item Name and User ID has already been taken.
        )

)
```

User model:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;

    public $currentPassword;
    public $newPassword;
    public $newPasswordConfirm;
    public $perfil;
    public $perfil_array = [];

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'currentPassword' => 'Palavra passe atual',
            'newPassword' => 'Nova palavra passe',
            'newPasswordConfirm' => 'Confirmar nova palavra passse',
            'created_at' =>  'Data Criação',
            'updated_at' =>  'Data Atualização',
        ];
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],                
        ];
    }
    public function getAuthAssignment() {
        return $this->hasMany(AuthAssignment::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

How can i remove all the permissions for the user i'm updating before updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how managed to do it after some research.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
    $itemsSaved = false;
    $permissionsList = Yii::$app->request->post()['User']['perfil_array'];
    if (!empty($permissionsList)) {
        $permissions = AuthAssignment::find()
        ->where(['user_id' => $id])->all();
        if (!empty($permissions)) {
            foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
                $permission->delete();
            }
        }
        foreach ($permissionsList as $permission) {
            $newPermission = new AuthAssignment;
            if ($newPermission->item_name != $permission) {
                $newPermission->item_name = $permission;
                $newPermission->user_id = $id;
            }
            if($newPermission->save()){
                print_r("okkkkkkkkk");
            } else {
                print_r($newPermission->getErrors());
            }
        } 
  }
  if ($model->save()) {
      $itemsSaved = true;
  } else {
      print_r($model->getErrors());die;
      return $this->render('update', [
      'model' => $model,]);
  }
  if ($itemsSaved) {
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
  }


}
```

I find all the permissions for that particular user and remove all of them before assigning new permissions. Don't know if it isthe best way to do it but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking if the entry exists, one way to do it would be to check if the user has the permission already.

```
if (!empty($permissionsList)) {

    // Get the authentication component
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

    foreach ($permissionsList as $permission) {

        // Check if the user has the permission
        if (!$auth->checkAccess($id, $permission)) {

            // Check if the permission exists
            if ($auth->getPermission($permission) !== null) {

                // Create the new permission and add it to the rbac system
                $newPermission = $auth->createPermission($permission);
                $newPermission->description = 'my cool description';                      
                $auth->add($newPermission);

            }             

            /* 
             * Once here we know that the permission exists, it 
             * was there before or we created it.
             * I am going to assume that the user exists.
             * We can go ahead and give that user the permission.
             */
            try {
                $auth->assign($newPermission, $id);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Yii::error($e, __METHOD__);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Now it's not thrwing the error but is not updating the user. It's redirecting to view when i click save but the user is not updated. Any clue on what's missing?

Comment: I updated the answer to use the application `authManager` component. Also updated the permission creation and assignment.

Comment: I would suggest splitting your question into two different ones, your original question, this one, was about an error updating the user permissions. It seems like that problem is solved, in that case you should mark this answer as accepted to indicate that the problem indicated in the question has been solved. Then I suggest posting another question, with all the *authentication* related code removed, that shows the problem you are having updating the user. Feel free to post the link to the question here and I will have a look, my guess is that you forgot to add some required property.

Comment: you right, that should be another topic. BTW i found why model wasn't updating, it has to do with validation rules. The main problem though is still not solved, i.e, it's not updatind the permissions after implementing your suggestion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you check in your database that, after calling `$auth->add($id,$permission);` there wasn't a new record on the auth_assignment table? If so, the only thing I can think of is that you are mixing up permissions and roles somewhere in your code. Did you follow the example on the Yii documentation? You don't assign permissions to users directly, you assign permissions to roles and assign roles to users. The result is less confusing and easier to manage.

Comment: would mind if i show you my code? Maybe skype or TV. Because i think i followed the documentation correctly. I'm not assiging permission to user directly. I do it through the auth_assignment table.

Comment: Skype or TV would not work that well. Do you have the code hosted in any public repository that I could clone? I could check it tomorrow.